# "Could not get the type info from component xml schema" when loading a page in SiteEdit 2009

Tags: inline, tridion

I enabled inline editing on SitEdit 2009 SP2 using the answer given here

[How do I enable inline field editing in SiteEdit when using an XSLT TBB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667640/how-do-i-enable-inline-field-editing-in-siteedit-working-when-using-an-xslt-tbb)

but I keep getting this error when loading the resulting page in SiteEdit:

> Sys.FormatException: Could not get the type info from component xml schema.
>   Field: cf_tcm:20-33457-64_content_header
>   XPath: [1]

My XSLT TBB fragment:

```xml
<xsl:if test="//*[local-name()='content_header'] != ''">
    <h1>
        <div>
            <tcdl:ComponentField name="content_header" index="0">
                <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='content_header']">
            </tcdl:ComponentField>
        </div>
    </h1>
</xsl:if>
```

The output in the published file:

```xml
<h1>
  <div>
    <span>
      <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: {"ID" : "cf_tcm:20-33457-64_content_header", "XPath" : "[1]", "IsMultiValued" : false} -->
      <tcdl:ComponentField name="content_header" index="0" SiteEditProcessed="true">
        Test
      </tcdl:ComponentField>
    </span>
  </div>
</h1>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: html content shows up now in the question

Comment: It does, but please take a moment to look up how highlighting of code fragments works here on StackOverflow. I now edited your question to use this format, but it may be helpful on future question/answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message means that the XPath in your `<!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: { ...} -->` command does not point to a field in the current Component. Given that your XPath shows up as `[1]`, that sounds pretty accurate.

You'll need to find the cause of the empty XPath being output. In your XSLT you mark the field with a `<tcdl:ComponentField>` wrapper. This wrapper is later processed by the "Enable Inline Editing" TBB to generate a corresponding `<!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field ... -->` command. Since the SiteEdit front-end needs an XPath to the field and the `tcdl:ComponentField` only contains the field name, the TBB will need to look up the XPath based on the field name.

The "Enable Inline Editing" TBB from SiteEdit 2009 looks up the current Component when processing `tcdl:ComponentField` by looking at the current resolved item (`engine.PublishingContext.ResolvedItem.Item.Id`). It then looks up the field in that Component to determine its XPath.

If you look at the package in the Template Builder, what is **the Component at the bottom of the Package list**? Does that Component contain a `content_header` field?

Comment: I had inline site edit tbb in 2 places. I am not sure why that was causing xpath not to resolve

Comment: I don't know that either, but I also notice that your published HTML still has the <tcdl:ComponentField> markings in there. Normally those are cleaned up by (the Cleanup Template in) the Default Finish Actions. You might want to check if that one is present and working.