# SDL Tridion SiteEdit 2009 SP2 XPath error when editing some components

Tags: tridion, tridion2009, siteedit

I am receiving the following error when trying to edit some of my Component Presentations using SiteEdit.

> Sys.FormatException: Could not get the type info from component xml
>   schema. Field: cf_tcm:32-204267_title XPath:
>   Content/custom:Content/custom:title[1]

It's strange because some of the Components with the same Template work fine (these do not have an image set,but the ones with an image set do not work).

Here is the code for my CT:

```html
<div class="column v-2 siteedit">
  <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond = "Component.thumbnail" -->
    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond = "Component.image" -->
      <a href="@@Component.Fields.image@@" class="fb ajax">
    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
    <img src="@@Component.Fields.thumbnail@@"  class="align-left"
         alt="@@thumbnail0.Metadata.alt@@" height="69" width="99"/>
    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond = "Component.image" -->
      </a>
    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
  <!-- TemplateEndIf -->    
  <h2>
    <tcdl:ComponentField name="title">@@Component.Fields.title@@</tcdl:ComponentField>
  </h2>
  <p>@@Component.Fields.summary@@</p>
</div>
```

(I have removed other editable fields just to make sure that it wasn't a problem with a specific field)

Any ideas?

**Update**
As requested here's my (anonymized) HTML, the 1st and 3rd components have the issue, the middle one is fine:

```html
<div class="general-content columns-three">
    <div class="column v-2 siteedit" style="height: 209px; ">
        <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {
            "ID" : "97829119-68f0-4e41-9862-b042d480cb71",
            "ComponentID" : "tcm:32-204859",
            "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:32-204536-32",
            "Version" : "2",
            "IsQueryBased" : false
        } -->
        <a href="http://REDACTED:84/_images/REDACTED.png?__Proxy=0" class="fb ajax" target="_self">
            <img src="/_images/REDACTED.gif" class="align-left" alt="REDACTED" height="69" width="99">
        </a>

        <h2>
            <span style="">
            <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: {
                "ID" : "cf_tcm:32-204267_title", 
                "XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:title[1]", 
                "IsMultiValued" : false
            } -->REDACTED
            </span>
        </h2>
      <p>REDACTED</p>
    </div>      

    <div class="column v-2 siteedit" style="height: 209px; ">
        <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {
            "ID" : "2933b5e0-2006-440d-bc03-2224650bdd7d",
            "ComponentID" : "tcm:32-204268",
            "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:32-204536-32",
            "Version" : "5",
            "IsQueryBased" : false
        } -->
        <h2> <span style="">
            <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: {
                "ID" : "cf_tcm:32-204268_title", 
                "XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:title[1]", 
                "IsMultiValued" : false} -->REDACTED</span>
           </h2>
           <p>REDACTED</p>
    </div>      

    <div class="column v-2 siteedit" style="height: 209px; ">
        <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {
            "ID" : "fac3c467-7c71-4be9-b319-8a35524ee172",
            "ComponentID" : "tcm:32-204860",
            "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:32-204536-32",
            "Version" : "2",
            "IsQueryBased" : false
        } -->
        <a href="http://REDACTED:84/_images/REDACTED.png?__Proxy=0" class="fb ajax" target="_self">
            <img src="/_images/REDACTED.gif" class="align-left" alt="REDACTED" height="69" width="99">
        </a>
        <h2> <span style="">
            <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: {
                "ID" : "cf_tcm:32-204269_title", 
                "XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:title[1]", 
                "IsMultiValued" : false
            } -->REDACTED</span>
        </h2>
        <p>REDACTED</p>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are constructing the tcdl yourself rather than using @@RenderComponentField(Field.Name, 0)@@?

Comment: It's how I was shown to do it. There's quite a lot of instances where I need a bit more control over how the field is rendered but you're right in this particular case I probably don't need it. Is that the problem?

Comment: Rob, What is you CT looks like. Did you add any C# TBBs prior to the DWT to get these thumbnails ?

Comment: No the thumbnail is a separate image on the component in this case.

Comment: Ok. I noticed this when you add any Components to package prior to this via C# TBB. I have to add the main component on top. If you're using TemplateBase "PutMainComponentOnTop()" is the one that does the trick.. Let me know if you need that sample code..

Comment: Are all components based on the same schema? And does that schema have a title field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I explained when that error message appears here: ["Could not get the type info from component xml schema" when loading a page in SiteEdit 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436067/could-not-get-the-type-info-from-component-xml-schema-when-loading-a-page-in-s)

Your use-case may be different from that question, the product always shows this for the same reason: it can't find a field (that is identified in a `<!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field` command) in the current Component (that is identified in the enclosing `<!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation` command).

Given your error message:

> cf_tcm:32-204267_title XPath: Content/custom:Content/custom:title[1]

It seems like Component `tcm:32-204267` doesn't have a field named `title`.

In these cases it is always easiest if you look at the HTML that SiteEdit ends up processing, so what your staging/preview server returns. Find the `title` field and its enclosing Component Presentation and verify that indeed that Component Presentation has a field named `title`.

If you'd like a more direct answer to "what am I doing wrong?", add the relevant HTML-with-the-SiteEdit-commands to your question and I'll update my answer to match.

---

**Update based on the HTML provided**

If I look at the IDs of the Component and Fields you provided:

1. Component: `tcm:32-204859` Field: `cf_tcm:32-204267_title`
2. Component: `tcm:32-204268` Field: `cf_tcm:32-204268_title`
3. Component: `tcm:32-204860` Field: `cf_tcm:32-204269_title`

The ID in the JSON is only used by SiteEdit to ensure some meaningless uniqueness. But in this case the Field ID seems to indicate from which Component the field comes.

If you then look at the data closely, you can see that for Component 2 the field points to the same Component. For Components 1 and 3 the fields actually point to another Component. Again, the `ID` properties of the Field commands are in themselves not used. But the relation between what works and what doesn't seems to coincide pretty well with the knowledge that SiteEdit loads the Schema of the Component indicated in the containing `Component Presentation` command and cannot find the field at the XPath indicated in the `Component Field` command.

I suspect that in #1 and #3 you have put some regular Component on the page, but are rendering the title of a Multimedia Component that is linked that Component. In #2 you are most likely rendering the title of an MMC that is explicitly put on the page.

Comment: Hi Frank, I saw that but it looked like a slightly different issue. I'll post the HTML

Comment: Added HTML Frank, showing 3 components, the first and last show the problem, the middle one works.

Comment: Hi Frank, Ryan Durkin took a look at my code and discovered that as you say the ID of the multimedia component was getting returned because of a bug in my implementation of GetComponent returning the wrong component since it was getting the component by type rather than by name.

Comment: Great to hear you got it sorted Rob.